# error: expected declaration before } token (when trying to compile)

Tags: c++, stack

I'm having a problem. I have the template and implementation for a stack in files **stack.h** and **stack.hpp**. Then I have an **in2out.cpp** file that converts infix expressions to outfix expressions and evaluates them. At the beginning of in2out.cpp I "#include stack.h". And inside **stack.h (which is my interface)** I "#include stack.hpp" **(stack.hpp is my implementation)**. I know this is weird but it's the way I'm required to do it.

Anyways, my problem is, when I'm trying to compile these 3 files together. I get only 1 error which is in stack.h (my interface, listed below). The error is:

```
In file included from in2post.cpp:7:
stack.h:49: error: expected declaration before â}â token
```

Line 49 is near the bottom. here is my stack.h file.

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


namespace cop4530 {

template<typename T>
class Stack {

 private:
 std::vector<T> v;

 public:
 Stack();
 ~Stack();
 Stack (const Stack<T>&);
 //Stack (Stack<T>&& );
 Stack<T>& operator= (const Stack <T>&);
 //Stack<T> & operator=(Stack<T> &&);
 bool empty() const;
 void clear();
 void push(const T& x);
 //void push(T && x);
 void pop();
 T& top();
 const T& top() const;
 int size() const;
 void print(std::ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const;

};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a);

template<typename T>
bool operator== (const Stack<T>& a, const Stack <T>& b);

template<typename T>
bool operator!= (const Stack<T>& a, const Stack <T>& b);

template<typename T>
bool operator< (const Stack<T>& a, const Stack <T>& b);

#include "stack.hpp"

}    //this is line 49

#endif
```

Here's my makefile:

```
CC = g++
FLAGS = -Wall -pedantic
DDD = -g

in2post.x: in2post.cpp stack.h stack.hpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(DDD) -o in2post.x in2post.cpp
```

EDIT: Here's the beginning of Stack.hpp: (tell me if I should change or add something)
EDIT2: I just decided to include the whole Stack.hpp. Some functions are blanked out cause I didn't need them or couldn't figure them out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(){}

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack(){
   v.clear();
}

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T> & S){
    v = S.v;
}
/*
template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack<T> &&){

}
*/
template<typename T>
Stack<T> & Stack<T>::operator=(const Stack<T> & S){
    v = S.v;
    return *this;
}
/*
template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack<T> & Stack<T>::operator=(Stack<T> &&){

}
*/
template<typename T>
bool Stack<T>::empty() const {
    return v.empty();
}

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::clear(){
    while (!v.empty())
        v.clear();
}

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& x){
    v.push_back(x);
}
/*
template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(T && x){

}
*/
template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::pop(){
    v.pop_back();
}

template<typename T>
T& Stack<T>::top(){
    return v[v.size()-1];
}

template<typename T>
const T & Stack<T>::top() const{
    return v[0];
}

template<typename T>
int Stack<T>::size() const {
    return v.size();
}

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::print(std::ostream & os, char ofc) const {
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    os << v[i] << ofc;
}

/*------------------NON-MEMBER GLOBAL FUNCTIONS-----------------*/

template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Stack<T> & a) {
    a.print(os);
    return os;
}


template <typename T>
bool operator==(const Stack<T> & a, const Stack<T> & b) {
    if(a.size() != b.size())
            return false;
    else {
        Stack<T> c = a;
        Stack<T> d = b;
        bool retVal = true;

        while(!c.empty()) {
            if(c.top() == d.top()) {
             c.pop();
             d.pop();
            }
            else {
             retVal = false;
             break;
            }
        }
    return retVal;
    }
}


template <typename T>
bool operator!=(const Stack<T> & a, const Stack<T> & b) {
    return !(a == b);
}

template <typename T>
bool operator<(const Stack<T> & a, const Stack<T> & b) {
    Stack<T> c = a;
    Stack<T> d = b;
    bool retVal = true;

    while(!c.empty()) {
        if(!(c.top() < d.top())) {
          retVal = false;
          break;
        }
        else {
          c.pop();
          d.pop();
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart it's the namespace. I suspect "stack.hpp" include header has some syntax issue. Why is it included at the end anyway?

Comment: Show us what's inside `stack.hpp`, something in there is probably causing the issue.

Comment: You may place the } before the include

Comment: Did you forget to close the namespace in stack.h?

Comment: I get errors when I place "#include stack.hpp". outside of the namespace or even at the top. I'm not sure why though

Comment: As PomfCaster wrote: Give us the content of Stack.hpp otherwise it's impossible to tell you what is causing the error!

Comment: I gave the beginning of Stack.hpp. the rest of the file is just a series of functions that aren't giving me errors. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Actually I decided to just write the whole stack.hpp in there

Comment: `operator<` has an extra closing brace.

Comment: You cannot include a standard header in a namespace. Include all headers at the very top (or, if you must, at the very bottom) of any file that uses them (but still inside the include guards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `operator<` in stack.hpp has an extra closing curly brace which is closing the namespace early.

Comment: Weird... I think that might've been a mishap in when I copied and pasted it to the website because it's not the same in my stack.hpp file... However, I don't think there's a namespace in stack.hpp though.

Comment: fixed the mistake. Sorry about that. But still getting an error for some reason. I'm going to look over it again to see if I can figure it out

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Turns out I had an extra curly bracket in stack.hpp, but it was several lines below the end of my code and I couldn't see it. LOL how embarassing. Thankyou!